# Decimal to duration in Sheets app

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

How to convert a decimal value to duration like:

`569,3` to `569:18:00`

The output should be a acceptable duration, not a "masked" concatenate like
`CONCATENATE(569;":";18;":";"00")`

The sheets app (can be Microsoft Excel, Google Sheets or Libre Office Calc, but preferably Google Sheets) should read as an acummulated time (elapsed time or duration) to make more formulas after.

Things that i already tried:
Using `TIME()` but the result will be locked to 24h

Comment: Could you please provide a few more examples or confirm that it is correct that you are assuming that the first part is simply the number of hours and you only care about converting the 0.3 part translating into 18 mins?

Comment: Simply divide this value by 24 - something like `=A2/24` - and then format the result with the format code `[HH]:MM:SS`

Comment: By the way, for LibreOffice-Calc you can see [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68755601/14094617)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)&":"&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(("0."&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))))/24,"mm:ss")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Lee`'s formula will produce a text string that Excel will broadly treat as a number when it realizes you wish it to.

You mention not having a "masked" concatenate and give an example of one that would be unacceptable. I'll point out that the example you give will be treated identically to `Lee`'s formula's results, near as my experiments can tell. So if his formula is A-OK, then your basic concatenation should be too. (Of course, it would get more complicated in tearing the value apart to build it, so the end formula would likely be more involved than `Lee`'s.)

However, in circumstances in which Excel has pretty good reason to believe you wish to use it "as is" — as a string — it will do so for most of them. Lookups of various sorts and "does this equal that" comparisons for example.

If you do standard "coercion" such as adding `+0` or `*1` to `Lee`'s formula, you get unhappy results. However, if you simply wrap his formula in a pair of parentheses (`()`), and THEN do the coercion, it becomes a real number.

That might not seem to matter, at least now in whatever usage you need to satisfy, but it might be of interest just so you know you are not leaving potential pitfalls in your wake. In your wake or not, pitfalls always seem to instead be ahead of you, in the end.

So wrap with `()` and coerce, and Excel will immediately make it a real boy, er, number.

But if that IS important to you, `JohnSUN`'s comment's formula does it simply and directly.

And if you didn't picture it before asking the question, but find the idea of it being a string, instead, but one that Excel can and will use as a number, wrapping his answer in a `TEXT()` function using his formatting string will also accomplish the task simply and directly.